# (Beginner Julia) Basic while loop won't run in Juno, but runs in Jupyter

Tags: loops, while-loop, jupyter-notebook, julia, juno-ide

I installed JuliaPro 1.4.1-1 this morning and opened up some beginner Julia tutorials.

The code below runs perfectly in a Jupyter Notebook, but gives an UndefVarError when I run it in Juno, whether I run it in the REPL or as a .jl file.

```
n = 0
while n < 4
    n += 1
    println(n)
end
```

When I run it as a .jl, the error message reads:

```
Error evaluating firsttest.jl

LoadError: UndefVarError: n not defined
in expression starting at C:\Users\Lipkin Hollow\JuliaPro-1.4.1-1\firsttest.jl:2
top-level scope at firsttest.jl:3
```

When I run it in REPL, the error reads:

```
ERROR: UndefVarError: n not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at .\none:3
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've run into current scoping rules in Julia: loops introduce their own scope, so you can't access a global variable from within the loop. The relevant documentation is [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/)

IJulia currently uses a package called [SoftGlobalScope.jl](https://github.com/stevengj/SoftGlobalScope.jl) to change this scoping behaviour, as it turned out to be one of the more controversial changes introduced in Julia version 1.0. That's why behaviour is currently different between IJulia/Jupyter Notebooks and other settings (i.e. REPL and Juno).

Note that this behaviour will change again in Julia version 1.5, which will bring the behaviour at the REPL in line with what you now see in Jupyter. The announcement for this can be found [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.5-dev/NEWS/#Language-changes-1).

In general though, the use of global variables in Julia is strongly discouraged for performance reasons, and you should look to organise your code in functions to make the most of Julia!

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful. How would you do a while-loop in Juno, then?

Comment: You have different options: either (1) wrap everything in a function `main() [your code here] end` and call `main()`, or (2) annotate the variable `n` in your loop as `global n` or (3) use Julia 1.5 (which I think currently requires building from source and is probably not advised for beginners!)

Comment: Thank you. Using main() worked. I haven't quite gotten the global declaration though. When I use the same code as I have in the question except for "global n = 0" instead of just "n = 0", it still gives me an UndefVarError. Sorry for splitting hairs -- I'm just trying to understand what Julia is doing, coming from a Python/R background.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear in my previous comment - you need to annotate the **loop** variable as global, i.e. `global n += 1` in your loop. `n = 0` automatically creates a global variable (as you are doing the assignment in global scope), you know need to let the loop know that it should be looking for `n` in that global scope, rather than in its own local scope (which it does by default). Python is different as loops don't have their own scope (which is why if you do `for i in range(5)` in Python you have `i=4` floating around outside the loop afterwards, in Julia `i` would be undefined)

Comment: This makes sense and answers my question perfectly. I'm able to reproduce it now. Thank you so much.